# roles.cache.find() for finding a role returning undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

I have the code below:

```
collector.on('collect', async (reaction, user) => {
    if (!user.bot) {
        let role = reaction.message.guild.roles.cache.find((role) => { return role.name === '️announcements-ping' });
        console.log(role);
        /* let userMember = await reaction.message.guild.members.fetch(user);
        userMember.roles.add(role); */
    }
});
```

It's supposed to add the `announcements-ping` role to whoever reacts to the message, but when I console log the variable `role` it returns undefined.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: It means role `announcements-ping` does not exist. It's not recommended to use role names, as they can change rapidly. Instead, use `role = reaction.message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.id === 'RoleID');`

Comment: It's recommend to use `.get()` if you're using an ID

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the role name is correct. If it's correct, maybe the role is not cached and you'll need to fetch it. [`.fetch()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/RoleManager?scrollTo=fetch) returns a promise, so make sure you `await` the results.

Check out the code below:

```js
collector.on('collect', async (reaction, user) => {
  if (user.bot) return;

  try {
    let roles = await reaction.message.guild.roles.fetch();
    // you can also get the role by id
    // let role = roles.cache.get('872088xxxxx0194211');
    let role = roles.cache.find((r) => r.name.toLowerCase() === '️announcements-ping');

    if (!role) return console.log(`Oops, I can't find the role`);

    let member = await reaction.message.guild.members.fetch(user);
    member.roles.add(role);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
});
```

[image]

Comment: This didn't work for me, I got the error message.

Comment: "oops i cant find the role"

Comment: Then there is no role named `announcements-ping` exists on the server. Have you double checked if it's the correct name?

Comment: Yup. I've even copy-pasted it to make sure

Comment: Have you tried to create a new role with a different name and update it in the code to check? I'm running out of ideas now.

Comment: I tried, here are some screenshots: [this](https://ibb.co/86BBk0b) and [this](https://ibb.co/kQ2r6RL).

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems valid, make sure that your role name is valid. (Case sensitive too)

With discord, it's recommended to use Ids instead. Visit this [page](https://support.discord.com/hc/en-us/articles/206346498-Where-can-I-find-my-User-Server-Message-ID-) if you don't know how to collect them.

```js
let role = reaction.message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.id === '️roleID');
// OR
let role = reaction.message.guild.roles.cache.get('️roleID');
```

Comment: Is there a way to get the ID using DiscordJS and not manually?

Comment: By using the role name to collect it and then use the id getter.

Comment: By any chance could you link a site explaining how to do that or edit your code or something? No pressure, just wondering C: